# Substring value retrieved from database in .NET / C#

Tags: c#, .net, database, while-loop

I'm using the following to read out values from my database:

```
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        newsLabel.Text += "<div style='float:left;'>" + reader["body"] + "</div>";
    }
```

I was wondering. How do I reduce the value of "body" to just 0,20 characters?

Is there a Substring function I can use?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that as shown below. Make sure to check for DbNull.

```
while (reader.Read()) 
        {
            string body = reader["body"] is DBNull ? "" : Convert.ToString(reader["body"]);

            if(body.Length > 20)
              body = body .Substring(0, 20);

            newsLabel.Text += "<div style='float:left;'>" + body  + "</div>";   
        }
```

Comment: This will throw an exception if the body is shorter than 20 characters.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the `body` column contains a string you can truncate it like this:

```
var body = (String) reader["body"];
var truncatedBody = body.Substring(0, Math.Min(body.Length, 20));
```

If the column can be `null` you will have to check for that before calling `Substring`.

`Substring` **will throw an exception** if the requested length of the substring is longer than the length of the actual string. That is why you have to use the minimum of the string length and the desired substring length.

If you do this a lot you can create an extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions {

  public static String Truncate(this String str, Int32 length) {
    if (length < 0)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length");
    if (str == null)
      return String.Empty;
    return str.Substring(0, Math.Min(str.Length, length));
  }

}
```

You can use it like this:

```
((String) reader["body"]).Truncate(20)
```

Comment: Many thanks, Martin :) I've been given a whole bunch of ways to do it. Thanks again for such a speedy reply.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do it in `Substring` in C#

```
newsLabel.Text += "<div style='float:left;'>" + Convert.ToString( reader["body"]).SubString(0,20) + "</div>";
```

read [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: (1) reader["Body"] is of type object and (2) the method is named `Substring`.

Comment: This will throw an exception if the body is shorter than 20 characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
reader["body"].ToString().Substring(0,20);
```

Comment: Many thanks. What a choice to choose from :) I tried Amitabh above and it worked great. Thank you

Comment: This will throw an exception if the body is shorter than 20 characters.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the answers here, you could also push this substring back to the database - as SQL has a SubString function.

e.g. if you were using Linq 2 Sql then the c# SubString method can get translated back to a SQL operation within the database - 
http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2010/04/15/understanding-linq-to-sql-4-data-retrieving-via-query-methods.aspx

Whether this is optimal or required depends on your application and database.

Hope that helps

Stuart

Answer (score 0):

```
while(reader.Read()) 
{
    string readBody = reader["body"] as string;
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(readBody))
    {
        if(readBody.Length > 20)
           newsLabel.Text = string.Format("{0}<div style='float:left;'>{1}</div>",
                                     newsLabel.Text, readBody.Substring(0,20));
        else
           newsLabel.Text = string.Format("{0}<div style='float:left'>{1}</div>",
                                     newsLabel.Text, readBody);
    }
}
```